# Delphi: GR32 blending alpha channel is depend on Clear() color

Tags: delphi, blending, graphics32

I used a picture with alpha channel and some section of image is not fully opaque. When I draw it on a `TImgView32` object that sections get a little color from `Clear()` color. Lets show it by a sample picture:

This is the original picture that you normally see in Photoshop:

[image]

And this is the result image when I draw it on a new layer in a GR32 object that I cleared it before with `Clear($00FF0000);`:

[image]

**The result is transparent like photohop one but that red halo is the problem.**

Or another color with `Clear($000000FF);`:

[image]

Note that as you know the color I used is fully transparent.

Here is the code I used to create above result:

```pascal
begin
  ImageList.Bitmaps.Add;     //ImageList is a TBitmap32List object
  LoadPNGintoBitmap32(ImageList.Bitmap[0], ImgPath+'test.png', DummyBool);

  BL:= TBitmapLayer.Create(ImgView.Layers);
  ImgID:=0;
  ScaleFactor:= 1;
  LayerPos:= Point(100, 100);

  with ImageList.Bitmap[ImgID] do
    ImageRect:= Rect(0, 0, Width, Height);

  {Auxilary variables}
  CanvasWidth:= ImageRect.Right{*2};   //Extending width for two icon.
  CanvasHeight:= ImageRect.Bottom;

  BL.Location:= FloatRect(
    LayerPos.X,
    LayerPos.Y,
    LayerPos.X + CanvasWidth * ScaleFactor,
    LayerPos.Y + CanvasHeight * ScaleFactor
  );

  with BL.Bitmap do
  begin
    {Init}
    SetSize(CanvasWidth, CanvasHeight);
    DrawMode:= dmBlend;
    Clear($00FF0000);

    {Insert image}
    Draw(0, 0, ImageRect, ImageList.Bitmap[ImgID]);
  end;

  if ScaleFactor<>1 then
    TDraftResampler.Create(BL.Bitmap);  //BL.Bitmap, because we used "Draw" method
end;
```

How to avoid this and get a clear result like photoshop one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see it works as designed, provided you're using the `cmBlend` [combine mode](https://graphics32.github.io/Docs/Units/GR32/Classes/TCustomBitmap32/Properties/CombineMode.htm). `cmBlend` doesn't take the alpha of the background into account and, as [the documentation](https://graphics32.github.io/Docs/Units/GR32/Types/TCombineMode.htm) states, should not be used to blend bitmaps:

> cmBlend - Fast blending of foreground color with the background color using the supplied alpha. This method is not suited for working and preserving alpha-channels. Use this more if you want to blend directly to the display buffer.

Use the `cmMerge` combine mode instead when both the foreground and the background alpha is significant.

Comment: Thanks for your comment BUT using `cmBlend` or `cmMerge` in `CombineMode` don't change anything.

Comment: You need to specify `DrawMode` and `CombineMode` on the **source** bitmap - not the destination bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem recently

the TImageList does not support transparency, so I had to use a TPngImageList when I wanted to load transparent png images into controls at runtime.

TPngImageList is available via a google search!

Comment: The OP edited his question to indicate that the image list being used is a [TBitmap32List](http://graphics32.org/documentation/Docs/Units/GR32_Image/Classes/TBitmap32List/_Body.htm) - which does support alpha.